# Windows Form, потеря иконки в task bar, при потере фокуса приложением

Tags: c#, winforms

Случайно обнаружил следующий баг: выставляю у формы свойство *FormBorderStyle* равное *FixedToolWindow*. Далее, при запуске приложения мгновенно(еще до того, как окно успело открыться), передаю фокус другому элементу(щелчок по проводнику). Так вот, в task bar'е не отображается иконка запущенного приложения, хотя само приложение открыто. Щелчок по запущенному приложению возвращает иконку на положенное ей место. Ниже предоставлю два скриншота. Это баг, или я недопонимаю что-то?
P.S.: по коду: он может быть любой, просто создать проект WF и изменить данное свойство будет достаточно для получения вышеописанного бага.
Успел передать фокус проводнику, иконка не отобразилась:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Передал фокус запущенному приложению(кликнул по нему, скриншот не захватил курсор), и иконка тут же появилась:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду благодарен за любые комментарии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FormBorderStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hw8kes41(v=vs.110).aspx)

> A tool window does not appear in the taskbar or in the window that appears when the user presses ALT+TAB.

Так и должно быть.

Более подробно: Установка свойства *FormBorderStyle* в *FixedToolWindow* добавляет к стилю окна значение *WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW*, которое предотвращает появление кнопки в панели задач. Однако, у формы есть другое свойство *ShownInTaskbar*, которое добавляет к стилю окна *WS_EX_APPWINDOW*, делающее противоположное (принудительное отображение кнопки в панели задач). Если окно имеет оба этих стиля, получается что-то вроде неопределенного поведения, т.к. нигде четко не написано, что имеет приоритет.

Answer (score 1):

У тебя три варианта. Первый и самый простой, это вернуть рамку, тем самым ты исправишь это неопределенной поведение. Во втором варианте ты можешь вручную, прямо в коде программы, устанавливать любые иконки. Для уверенности можешь отлавливать события фокуса и перерисовывать иконку. Третий вариант, он же самый интересный, ты можешь полностью отказаться от стандартного интерфейса и нарисовать свой собственный. Тем самым ты получишь и иконку и безрамочность.

Comment: Нарисовать свой собственный...очень заинтересовала эта тема. Куда копать, не подскажете? Мыслей много, но может быть есть статья\учебник, с чего можно начать.

Comment: Создаешь например PictureBox и рисуешь в нем, или где-то рисуешь/берешь картинки и отрисовываешь их в PictureBox, вешает события на этот элемент и дорисовываешь все что хочешь, меняешь картинки, делаешь анимации и тд.